# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n (\beta+k/n)$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n (\beta+k/n)$, where $\beta$ is the unique root of $(x+1)^{x+1}=e x^x$, where $e$ is the natural number, $\approx 2.718281828459$

What occurs? Let $\beta$ be arbitrary. Computations show that if $\beta$ is small, say $<=0.54$, then the limit is $0$;  but if $\beta=0.55$ implies the limit is $+\infty$!

Infinite product. Can we find a exact form of the $n$ product?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Euler–Maclaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) with [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_remainder_term). For any $\beta>0$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\log(\beta+k/n)&=\int_0^n\log(\beta+x/n)\,dx
\\&+\frac{\log(\beta+1)-\log\beta}2-\frac1{12n\beta(\beta+1)}+r_n,
\\r_n&=O\left(\int_0^n\frac{dx}{(n\beta+x)^3}\right)=O(1/n^2),
\\\int_0^n\log(\beta+x/n)\,dx&=n\big((\beta+1)\log(\beta+1)-\beta\log\beta-1\big).
\end{align}
Now if $\beta$ is the given root, the last expression vanishes, and we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\log(\beta+k/n)=\frac{\log(\beta+1)-\log\beta}2,$$ that is, the desired limit (exists and) equals $\sqrt{1+1/\beta}$.

Alternatively, write $$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\beta+\frac kn\right)=\frac1{n^n}\prod_{k=1}^n(n\beta+k)=\frac{\Gamma(n\beta+n+1)}{n^n\ \Gamma(n\beta+1)}$$ and use [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling%27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function) for the gamma function.

Comment: Amazing problem for the specific $\beta$